# Statistical test to decide whether the resistances are randomly drawn from a distribution or if there was (deterministic) process

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to find a statistical test which helps me to decide if a set of resistance measurements come from a (normal) distribution (due to production tolerance) or from a process (e.g. aging).

Let's say have 6 resistances in different aging states. For each of them I have the measurements of the last couple weeks with one resistance each day. I took those measurements and plotted the mean value in the plot below. From the visual interpretation there could be a linear time correlation due to aging or any other process. But still it could be just pure chance that they are in this way.

Question:
Is there a statistical test to decide whether the resistances are randomly drawn from a distribution or if there was deterministic process.

---

My Idea:
H0: Samples drawn from random distribution
H1: Process leading to this (linear) behavior

But I don't really know how to continue. Should I try regression and look at the p value, to see if the data is significant. And if so, wouldn't it be better not to use the mean values but each value on it own for each machine? But then I loose the nice property of independent variables (since measurements of the same resistance would surely not be independent).

I'm new to the field of statistics, so feel free to correct or suggest good sources for my problem. General topics names to read on are welcome as well.

[image: Resistance measurements over time]

Comment: Drawing 'random' points on a computer is typically a deterministic process! So this isn't in general possible. You could instead ask the question "is the data distributed according to a given distribution P?" and upon seeing the data answer either "it could be the case" or "it is unlikely".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I know or at least know how to search for ways to check a certain distribution. Lets assume the data points come from a linear function y = a*x + b, how could I test for my assumption statistically? Thanks in advance